# Python Autocompletion

Tags: python

Is there any option for Python autocomplete to work properly in Blender?

Currently it shows under <kbd>Tab</kbd> all the possible options that were entered previously in the code. It doesn't make any sense to use this feature.

Maybe you need to set something up somewhere in the Blender to make it work like in any eclipse VS editor?

[image]

Comment: That will be very hard to achieve IMO, you need to do it in the User Interface, and a separated python linter, which might make the text editor more complicated

Answer (score 4):

The terminal has autocompletion with the actual properties of objects when you press `tab`, which works very well to explore the available syntax in the API.

[image]

There's no real way to access bpy from IDEs such as VSCode. But you can get pretty close with [fake-bpy-module](https://github.com/nutti/fake-bpy-module), which emulates many of the properties and will give you an advantage as a developer with a good integration of many other python packages.

[image]

Comment: can also build `bpy` as a python module. In which case will autocomplete for most python editors. (can confirm for vim)

Comment: The `fake-bpy-module` worked well for me, Python 3.10 and Blender 4.0. Paired with the [Blender Development extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cgpython.blender-development-experimental-fork) (the CGI fork which works on 4.0) I could get the development experience that I was expecting.